# Guzzle client in Laravel: InvalidArgumentException: "No method is configured to handle the form_params config key"

Tags: php, api, laravel-4, guzzle

I am trying to use Guzzle client to post requests to an API, and I am getting an error message saying,

> InvalidArgumentException: "No method is configured to handle the form_params config key"

This is what I have tried:

```
$response = $this->guzzle->post("https://example.com",[
                'form_params'=> [
                    'client_id'=>$this->client_id,
                    'authorization_code'=>$this->authorization_code,
                    'decoder_query'=> $this->requestQuery
                  ],
            ]
        );
```

`$this->requestQuery` is a JSON request.

Comment: Have you tried adding (or is it possible for you to add) "form_params" when you setup your guzzle client, before calling the post method and see if that helps? You should be able to pass your config array to the guzzle Client constructor

Comment: I'm getting the same error. Did you solve this?

Comment: $response = $this->guzzle->post("https://example.com",[
                'body' => array(
                'client_id'=>$this->client_id,
                'authorization_code'=>$this->authorization_code,
                'decoder_query'=> json_encode($this->requestQuery),
    
            )]);

with this syntax I am getting it woking..

Answer (score 4):

```
$response = $this->guzzle->post("https://example.com", [
    'body' => [
        'client_id'         => $this->client_id,
        'authorization_code'=> $this->authorization_code,
        'decoder_query'     => json_encode($this->requestQuery),
    ]
]);
```

with this syntax I am getting it woking..

Answer (score 2):

you are probably using a Guzzle version that's before 6.0.  update to the latest version and 'form_params' will work just fine. i had the same issue since i was on 5.x version

```
composer require 'guzzlehttp/guzzle:6.0.1'
```

and make sure you update your dependencies:

```
composer update
```

you'll then see it'll pull in "guzzlehttp/psr7 (1.0.0)" as well.  hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

For me, this ended up being an problem with the actual Guzzle package not being correct. It loaded a version from cache that wasn't the the PSR7 version.

After clearing composer cache

`php composer.phar clear-cache`

I simply did a new composer install and installed just fine, while fixing the error.